# How to add a new line in a textbox's text?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, textarea, multiline

I have an `ASP.NET Textbox` control. It's `Multiline` property is set to true, effectively making it an HTML `textarea` element.

The text of the textbox is set as,

```
Text="New\r\nLine\r\nRequired"
```

As you can guess, I am trying to display the words in the text in separate lines. However, the Text is displayed exactly as it is entered.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: while entering text in textbox you want to display text in new line or while populating it from source?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```